# How to extract particular word(s) from the list of sentences using Python NLP. These word(s) are Parts of Medical equipments

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, data-science, spacy

I want to extract Medical Equipment part names from the list of sentences.
These sentences are recorded actions taken on a support request which might include replacement of a part or acknowledging a part is in a bad state.

Here are the sample sentences-

1. Found [Some equipment part] on both side not working.
2. Narrowed problem down to the [Some equipment part].
3. Needed a [Some equipment part] replacement.
4. Assisted with troubleshooting, found [Some equipment part] is most likely bad.
5. [Some equipment part] won't go down, will order part.

I want to extract "[Some equipment part]" from the above sentences.

Things I've already tried-
First, I've filtered the sentences using Sentiment Analysis. Considering only the ones which have a negative sentiment or have "replace" text in them.

1. Using NLTK, After POS tagging using RegexpParser on a defined grammer = "NP : {<VB.*><NN.*>+<NN.*>+|<VB.*>*<NN.*>+}"
2. Using Spacy, After POS tagging and dependency, filtering based on Verb, Noun relationship - token.dep_ in ['dobj'] and token.pos_ == 'NOUN'

The above approaches gives me a lot of meaningless output.
Please, let me know if there is anything which can be of help.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you would benefit from looking at Named Entity Recognition (NER). I would be curious if SpaCy would be able to pick these out as PRODUCT entities.

Comment: Spacy's "en_core_web_sm" model doesn't recognize the Medical Equipment as PRODUCT entities.

Answer (score 0):

You're likely going to need to train the Spacy [Named Entity Recognition](https://spacy.io/usage/training#ner) to label tokens as "Medical Equipment". That way, you can parse the text and locate the equipment based on the NER label.

This will require you produce some training data with the medical equipment entities specified. Skipping this step may be possible by looking for PRODUCT entities, but you will likely miss entities because your use case is more specific than the generic product's spacy is trained to detect.

Once you've trained the model to identify the new Medical Equipment entities, you can locate them via

```py
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_medicalner')
doc = nlp('some text')

for token in doc:
  if token.label_ == 'Medical Equipment':
    print('token {} is Medical Equipment'.format(token.text))
```

Comment: I followed the steps mentioned in Spacy NER training guide and was able to extract the Medical Equipments part names as per my training data. But i'm not sure how can i evaluate how effective it is. By effective i mean out of 100 parts how many i was able to recognize. Thanks for the help!

Comment: TRAIN_DATA = [
        ("Uber blew through $1 million a week", {"entities": [(0, 4, "ORG")]}),
        ("Google rebrands its business apps", {"entities": [(0, 6, "ORG")]})]

nlp = spacy.blank("en")
optimizer = nlp.begin_training()
for i in range(10):
    for text, annotations in TRAIN_DATA:
        nlp.update([text], [annotations], sgd=optimizer)
nlp.to_disk("test_model")
nlp2 = spacy.load('test_model')
for text, _ in TRAIN_DATA:
    doc = nlp2(text)
    print("Tokens", [(t.text, t.ent_type_, t.ent_iob) for t in doc])

"Uber and Google are not recognized as ORG"

Comment: once you've trained your model, you can use it `nlp(text_with_medeqip_ents))` on some other text with medical equipment in them that the model hasn't been trained on, and check the `doc.ents`. You can determine how many it gets correct/incorrect in your test set.